# “MDM” for Home use?

Tags: macos, ios, remote-desktop, ipados

Good Hello… I was wondering if there was an equivalent to an MDM for home use… I have a number of Apple devices, and (this may sound lazy) instead of running around, tracking them down and updating them 1-by-1, I would like the ability to just push out the updates from my Mac… I *thought* RDC used to do this, but I must have been dreaming…

Comment: What have you tried already and what problems did you have?  Perhaps we can help you with those specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my solution, it's not the best but it works for me.

I used Apple Configurator to erase and set my kids iPhones up as a a supervised device. From there, I got them all set up as a new user.

I created a few different configuration profiles with all of the settings I would like. 1 of them has all the wireless access points they might need, the other is the restrictions.

I set all of the restrictions that they can and can not do, set the apps they are only allowed to have, and set the content ratings. In this, I also hide the App Store.

From there, I used Screen Time to set their usage for the apps that they have remaining. They can't really use the device after bedtime unless they ask for it, like listening to audible books, etc...

My only drawback is that I need to manually update the apps on the device by removing the restrictions profile. But this does allow me to get my hands on the device to make sure everything is ok.

I hope that helps, it's kind of a quick overview.

Answer (score -2):

I have kinda tinkered with Apple Configurator and have looked at JAMF, but get lost at the whole “Name of Organization” and making a certificate… Configurator won’t allow me to use my home email/Apple ID address, so get kinda stuck there…

Comment: Please do not post comments and or requested information as answers, as answer are for answers not comments or requested information. Make edits to your question as appropriate and or make comments to an answer once you have enough reputation to do so. Please delete these non-answer posts you've made as answers.

Answer (score -2):

... and I did just find [this article](https://www.imore.com/how-update-your-ios-devices-using-apple-configurator-2) which talks about using Configurator in a home environment, so perhaps I'll take a closer look...

Comment: Please do not post comments and or requested information as answers, as answer are for answers not comments or requested information. Make edits to your question as appropriate and or make comments to an answer once you have enough reputation to do so. Please delete these non-answer posts you've made as answers.